# Qual pratica recomendada para checar se a função Ajax do jQuery está presente e é reconhecido pelo navegador, alguém sabe dizer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Qual pratica recomendada para checar se a função Ajax do jQuery está presente e é reconhecido pelo navegador, alguém sabe dizer?

```
// forma 1
if (!$.ajax) {
  alert ('Status xhr: não suporta Ajax');
 return false;
}
// forma 2
if (typeof $.ajax !== 'function') {
  alert ('Status xhr: não suporta Ajax');
 return false;
}
```

Em muitos dos **exemplos** no site do Mozilla MDN a condição para teste de funções de acordo com a **forma 1** e bem usada, de uma olhada:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: por gentileza quem negativou favor dar detalhes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize `jQuery.support.ajax` ou `$.support.ajax`

```
if (!$.support.ajax) {
    alert("Status xhr: não suporta Ajax");
}
```

Comment: Ótimo Paulo, obrigado, ainda não conhecia a função support, alem de que a dica do site Official na pagina da função também é bem relevante em usar a biblioteca Modernizr em vez disso, mas em quanto o projeto foi modelado assim, será de grande ajuda.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

Comment: Ainda não foi desativada essa função no jQuery, por isso, enquanto utilizar uma versão jQuery compatível, não existirá necessidade de utilizar o Modernizr.

Comment: Segundo a documentação, foi marcado como obsoleto no 1.9 e a intenção era de uso interno da biblioteca. Eu não recomendaria o uso, apesar de ser uma sintaxe elegante.

Answer (score 0):

Peguei o código em http://programmerguru.com/ajax-tutorial/browser-support/

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var xmlhttp; 
      function checkAJAXSupport() {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
          xmlhttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
          alert("Yes. Your browser must be one among them - Mozilla, Safari, Chrome, Rockmelt, IE 8.0 or above");
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
          try {
            xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            alert("Yes. Your browser must be IE");
          } 
          catch (e) {
            try {
              xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              alert("Yes. Your browser must be IE");
            } 
            catch (e) {}
          }
        }  if (!xmlhttp) {
          alert("No. Giving up Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance. Your browser is outdated!");
          return false;
        } 
 } 
</script>
```

Comment: Marlon, obrigado pela ajuda, mas esse código que postou já utilizei e o que busco é apenas confirmar de forma simples se o navegador reconhece como a função do jQuery no navegado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o When na sua requisição

```
    $.when( $.ajax ).then(function( data, textStatus, 
      jqXHR ) {
      alert( jqXHR.status ); // Alerts 200
    })
    .catch(function() {
      alert ('Status xhr: não suporta Ajax');
    })
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo apoio amigo, mas o que busco é apenas checar se existe a função e se o navegador reconhece para ser usada no futuro, isso da forma mais simples possivel.

Comment: Compreendi errado a pergunta , perdão , se eu achar alguma maneira de isso ser possível eu faço outra resposta

Comment: Editei a pergunta devido a sua observação.

Comment: escrevi uma nova resposta , mudando um pouco o modelo de como você testa o ajax mas que possa funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro você pode criar uma variavel para fazer um requisição ajax qualquer

Dai dentro da função você vai testando os navegadores possiveis , se não aceitar retorna um erro

```
    function ajaxFunction() {
      var xmlHttp;

      try {
       // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
       xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      catch (e) {
        // Internet Explorer
        try  {

           xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

        }
        catch (e) {
          try {
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
          catch (e) {
             alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");

             return false;
         }

    }
```

Comment: Eu não achei uma forma muito simples de conseguir fazer essa verificação, essa foi a mais tranquila que eu achei